# formsubmit.co using AJAX is sending empty emails

Tags: html, ajax, forms, form-submit

i am using formsubmit.co service and i want to use their AJAX method for submitting the message and the email of the user to my email address.
the problem is the form is submitted but the form data is not submitted and i cannot see the value of the email and message inputs after checking my email. so there are some emails in my inbox but when i open them, i cannot see who has sent them to me with what message.
this is my code:

```
<form action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="email from formsubmit">
                <div class="Comment-rows">
                    <div class="Comment-form">
                        <div class="Comment-InputBox">
                            <input id="CommentEmail" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="Comment-rows">
                    <div class="Comment-form">
                        <div class="Comment-InputBox textarea">
                            <textarea id="CommentMessage" required name="message" placeholder="message">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="Comment-form-Button">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <span>send</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/MyEmail@gmail.com',
        dataType: 'json',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        data: {
            email: document.querySelector('#CommentEmail').value,
            message: document.querySelector('#CommentMessage').value
        },
        success: (data) => console.log(data),
        error: (err) => console.log(err)
    });
    </script>
```

where am i making a mistake?

Comment: Your ajax request is not triggered when the send button is pressed, it just runs as the page loads. Also is the _subject field needed in the request?

Answer (score 1):

are you indcluding jquery?
if yes then call event after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your methods here.
})
```